# How to push var:var to array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var fieldArr = [];
dimensions.forEach(function (dimension) {
  fieldArr.push({dimension.id:dimension.name});
});
```

This generates an error.

What I'm trying to do is given this `dimensions`

```
{
    id: abc
    name: ddd
},
 {
    id: aaa
    name:kkk
 }
```

I want the `fieldsArr` to look like this

```
[abc] -> ddd
[aaa] -> kkk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to populate an object rather than an array.

Javascript

```
var dimensions = [{
        id: "abc",
        name: "ddd"
    }, {
        id: "aaa",
        name: "kkk"
    }],
    fieldArr = {};

dimensions.forEach(function (dimension) {
    fieldArr[dimension.id] = dimension.name;
});

console.log(fieldArr);
```

Output

```
Object {abc: "ddd", aaa: "kkk"}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/z7JZf/)

Answer (score 0):

Then `fieldArr` shouldn't be an array, but an object.

```
var fieldArr = {};

dimensions.forEach(function (dimension) {
  fieldArr[dimension.id]  = dimension.name;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

simply

```
fieldArr[dimension.id] = dimension.name
```